# Кто объяснит в чем проблема с добавлением в БД?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужен ответ или совет куда копать искать или кто может подскажет по человечески. я новичок и мало пока что понимаю. Вопрос такой. почему при добавлении новой сроки в БД, если ввожу в combobox вручную данные, то при поиске  по таким же критериям все находится (фильтруется). если выбираю из списка, то при поиске добавленная строка не находится, хотя в БД она есть. насколько я понял копать нужно именно в коде при добавлении строк.

```
 Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;

                if (main != null)
                {
                    DataRow nRow = main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    int rc = main.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;
                    nRow[0] = rc;
                    nRow[1] = cbType.Text;
                    nRow[2] = cbCategory.Text;
                    nRow[3] = dtpDate.Value.Date;
                    nRow[4] = tbSum.Text;
                    //nRow[5] = tbTotal.Text;
                    nRow[6] = tbComments.Text;

                    main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nRow);
                    main.accountingTableAdapter.Update(main.база_данныхDataSet.Accounting);
                    main.база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
                    main.dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    cbType.Text = " ";
                    cbCategory.Text = " ";
                    dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    tbSum.Text = " ";
                   // tbTotal.Text = " ";
                    tbComments.Text = " ";
                }
```

Comment: Если в БД данные появляются как надо, то тут вопрос скорее не в том, как вы данные добавляете, а в том как вы их потом извлекаете из базы.

Comment: делаю подключение к базе и отправляю запрос с выбором между двумя датами и по категории. категория также выбирается из выпадающего списка комбобокса. даты выбираются из datetimepicker.

Comment: Это просто слова, без кода они смысла не имеют. У вас же не общая и не концептуальная проблема, а проблема со вполне конкретным кодом. Вот и добавьте ваш код в вопрос, укажите, какие данные в БД есть, укажите какой запрос вы отправляете и что получаете на выходе.

Comment: я в прошлом своем вопросе все указал но никто не ответил. может вы сможете?  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128499/%d0%a1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: дайте угадаю, после перезапуска прложения, эта новая строка начинает появляться при тех же значениях фильтра, верно?

Comment: Эта строка вообще в БД попадает?

Comment: @tym32167 мне кажется проблема кроется именно при добавлении данных. поскольку добавление вручную что в самой таблице что через форму в ручную потом фильтруется при поиске

Comment: Да в БД попадает и сохраняется в ней.

Comment: Если я удалю ее из базы она не показывается при фильтре.

Comment: в базу данных строка попадает в любом случае.  но вот отображается при фильтрации только если введу первый параметр (Тип) вручную

Comment: Про удаление и понял. Я про другое спрашиваю. Вы когда добавляете строку через вашу программу, эта строка сохраняется в БД?

Comment: Так стоп. Я не понял. Вы без типа пытаетесь фильтровать что ли?

Comment: строка добавляется. фильтруется и по типу и с выбором промежутка. но если в ручную добавляю тип в форме добавления то новые строки показываются в форме поиска. если из выпадающего списка то не показываются

Comment: есть простой способ проверить что происходит. Поставьте брейкпоинт там, где выполняете поиск и поглядите, какие значения вы отправляете в запрос для поиска